# IOS Charts line chart view Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, linechart, ios-charts

I have been using IOS Charts library for my application. I have table view cells that includes line chart, pie chart and bar chart. For the first time I entered application there is no problem about showing charts but, when I pinch zoom into line chart view I am getting following error in the AxisRendererBase class.
`Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN`. If I disable pinch zoom it works fine. I do not understand the problem and my configureCell method is following.

```
func configureLineChart(xTitle:IndexAxisValueFormatter, index:Int) {
    lineChartView.data?.setDrawValues(false)
    lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    lineChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1)
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 45
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 8.0)!
    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xTitle
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = index
    lineChartView.xAxis.spaceMin = 0.5
    lineChartView.xAxis.spaceMax = 0.5
    lineChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    //lineChartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
    lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = true
}
```

When I tried to debug there is following image in my lldb. [image: IOS Charts fatal error image]

I have searched and tried other answers on StackOverFlow. However, what I have tried did not work. What could be the reason of it and how can I fix it ?

Edit: In my cellForRowAt method

```
    let cell = grafikTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chartCell") as? ChartsCell

    cell?.lineChartView.data = MainGrafikVC.lineChartDataArray[indexPath.row]
    cell?.barChartView.data = MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row]        
    cell?.barChartView.isHidden = false
    cell?.lineChartView.isHidden = false

    if MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row].dataSetCount != 0 {
cell?.configureBarChart(xTitle: MainGrafikVC.xTitleArray[indexPath.row], index: MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row].getDataSetByIndex(0).entryCount, chartData: MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray[indexPath.row], chartType: Servisler.servisListesi[MainGrafikVC.indexler[indexPath.row]].chartType)
cell?.lineChartView.isHidden = true
    }
    if MainGrafikVC.lineChartDataArray[indexPath.row].dataSetCount != 0 {
    cell?.configureLineChart(xTitle:MainGrafikVC.xTitleArray[indexPath.row] , index: MainGrafikVC.lineChartDataArray[indexPath.row].getDataSetByIndex(0).entryCount)
    cell?.barChartView.isHidden = true
    }
```

When user wants to add chart to my main table view following code works.

```
if (Servisler.servisListesi[MainGrafikVC.indexler[MainGrafikVC.listIndex]].chartType == "line") {
    self.createLineChart()
}

if (Servisler.servisListesi[MainGrafikVC.indexler[MainGrafikVC.listIndex]].chartType == "bar" || Servisler.servisListesi[MainGrafikVC.indexler[MainGrafikVC.listIndex]].chartType == "clustered") {
    self.createBarChart()
}
```

In my createLineChart method

```
func createLineChart() {
    let data = LineChartData()        
    var lineChartEntry1 = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<x1.count {
        lineChartEntry1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(x1[i]) ?? 0.0))
    }
    let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry1, label: "1")
    data.addDataSet(line1)        
    if (x2.count > 0) {
        var lineChartEntry2 = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<x2.count {
            lineChartEntry2.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(x2[i]) ?? 0.0))
        }
    let line2 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry2, label: "2")
    data.addDataSet(line2)
    }

    if (x3.count > 0) {
        var lineChartEntry3 = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<x3.count {
            lineChartEntry3.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(x3[i]) ?? 0.0))
        }
        let line3 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry3, label: "3")
        data.addDataSet(line3)
    }

        MainGrafikVC.lineChartDataArray.append(data)
        MainGrafikVC.barChartDataArray.append(BarChartData())
        MainGrafikVC.xTitleArray.append(IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: xTitle))
}
```

Comment: what is your pod version?

Comment: In my podfile.lock   - Charts (3.1.1):
    - Charts/Core (= 3.1.1)
  - Charts/Core (3.1.1) @RazibMollick

Comment: cell?.configureLineChart() has two arg, how did you call from cellForRowAt method?

Comment: I have miswrote that line I have edited my answer.

Comment: Could you post createLineChart() code?

Comment: Seems your code is okay. see this link https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/3352

Answer (score 1):

Your `interval` value is `NaN` (not a number).  This is the reason for the error.

You need to track down where that is coming from.  You can test a `Double` to see if it is `Nan` with `.isNaN`.

For example:

```
if interval.isNaN {
    interval = 0
}
```

---

If `interval` goes negative, then `log10` will return `Nan`.  Taking the `log10` of `0` isn't good either.  Values near `0` will yield large negative values.  You should take all of these into account.

---

You also appear to be using `Int` to truncate the value to an integer.  Use the `floor` function to do this:

Replace:

```
Double(Int(log10(interval)))
```

with:

```
floor(log10(interval))
```

Comment: Actually, I couldn't see why interval is NaN? Is interval values in the x-axis ?

Comment: Is it possible for `interval` to go negative?  That would cause `log10` to return `NaN`.

Comment: try `floor(log10(fabs(interval)))`

Comment: I tried but, it also did not work. What is the interval are they values in the x axis or y axis?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I haven't used iOS-charts.  Could you post the code of routine where the crash is actually happening?  That might give clues as to the use of interval and its range of values.

Comment: Are there settings for maximum and minimum zoom level?  Perhaps you are just going outside of the bounds of what iOS-charts can do which results in this error.

Comment: I have edited my question could you please take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if I tried these solutions none of them worked properly for me. So, I have added isNaN control in the AxisRendererBase.swift class in the Charts library. Now, 98th line of AxisRendererBase class should look like following,

```
if labelCount == 0 || range <= 0 || range.isInfinite || range.isNaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue and there's no need to fiddle with the classes in the library, but force set your min and max values if there's no data to calculate them from.

If there's no data to calculate them from then they'll be negative and positive infinity and that causes the crash to happen.

For my code the fix went as follows:

```
//If less than two items in line
//Force min and max to avoid range crash in library
if doubleValueArray.compactMap({ $0 }).count <= 2 {
    chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    chartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100
} else {
    chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = lineChartData.yMin
    chartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = lineChartData.yMax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue by editing AxisRendererBase class.
my error was same as yours.
and it hits that error at line 119

replace your Double(Int(log10(interval))) to **floor(log10(fabs(interval)))**

Error

```
AxisRendererBase.swift
    let intervalMagnitude = pow(10.0, Double(Int(log10(interval)))).roundedToNextSignficant() //error line
```

Solved

```
AxisRendererBase.swift
      let intervalMagnitude = pow(10.0, floor(log10(fabs(interval)))).roundedToNextSignficant()
```

++
if it doesn't work,
please don't set your chart when records.isEmpty.

like

```
if(!records.isEmpty){
   showChart()
}
```